# Locating TreeObject in large Tree

Tags: eclipse, tree, treeview, swt, jface

I have a large tree and I can 'select' (i.e.highlight) any node of it. But if I have a large tree with all nodes expanded the user still needs to manually scroll down or up in order to locate the highlighted element. Is there a way which not only highlights the selected element but also locates it by automatically scrolling up/down in the tree?

```
TreePath path = createTreePath(editorID, treeObject);
getTreeViewer().setSelection(new TreeSelection(path), true);
getTreeViewer().refresh();
getTreeViewer().jumpToSelectedElement(true); // I need something like this. I made up the name of this imaginary method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public void reveal(Object elementOrTreePath)
```

As its name suggests `elementOrTreePath` can be a tree path or just an element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used getTreeViewer().reveal(treeObject); But nothing really happens. The item gets highlighted as usual but the focus does not 'jump' there

Comment: "reveal" is not meant to change the focus and selection as well. Those are other methods you could also call.